# Javascript Document Structure Obj vs Func

Tags: javascript, architecture, structure

I've seen a few ways of structuring a large, shared js document and I'm trying to understand which approach to follow.

One approach I've seen employed in web projects involving lots of unrelated function calls has been to define each call as a method of a shared parent object (minimizing globals and simulating namespacing).

```
var parentObj = {
    someMethod: function() {
        $('.slideshow').animate({});
    },
    someOtherMethod: function() {
        $('.accordian').on('click', function() {
            console.log('etc, etc');
        });
    }
};
```

Another method I've seen has been to use a parent function;

```
var parentFunc = function() {
    this.someMethod = function() {
        $('.slideshow').animate({});
    };

    this.someOtherMethod = function() {
        $('.accordian').on('click', function() {
            console.log('etc, etc');
        });
    };
};
```

And then initializing the required methods when needed;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    parentObj.someMethod();
    parentFunc.someOtherMethod();
});
```

Questions:

Are there any operational differences between these two ways of structuring a javascript document?

Is one a better (or more generally accepted) practice than the other?

In terms of code reuse, is there an advantage to using one or the other (such as instantiating a new instance of a method, such as a second slideshow or accordion)?

Answer (score 1):

From operational side they are same.  Both of these sub-functions are compiled every time, when function is called.

There is also [Prototype](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_math.asp) way - in this case of declaration, function is declared one time and distributed to other functions.

From side of performance, Prototype way is more appropriate way.